# Connection in laravel phpmyadmim

Tags: php, laravel, env

I am doing a project in `laravael` framework.

I'm trying to open some pages. It is showing an error:

> at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'phpmyadminpd', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 47

My `.env` file is:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=wdIYfgjVOzyDfchid9nBIlOzL4uIAYuY

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=dbname  
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=phpmyadminpd

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Comment: Please remove api key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209536/laravel-5-database-issue

Answer (score 1):

PHPMYADMIN is just a web interface to deal with MySQL and has nothing to do with this.

If an app needs to deal with a database, such a Laravel app, it needs to get connected via the connection configuration files or the env files the usual stack.

Answer (score 1):

From the phpMyAdmin docs:

> **Configuration**
>
> All configurable data is placed in config.inc.php in phpMyAdmin’s
>   toplevel directory. This file only needs to contain the parameters you
>   want to change from their corresponding default value in
>   libraries/config.default.php

Example documentation for reference:
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#config-examples

Answer (score 0):

**PHPMYADMIN** is just a database management tool. It doesn't have to do anything with Laravel.

You have to deal with MySql. Make sure you put correct MySql database things correctly here

```
DB_DATABASE=dbname          //your database name  
DB_USERNAME=root           //your database user
DB_PASSWORD=phpmyadminpd   //your database password
```

I hope this will help you.