# Laravel Error using MAMP: PDOException in Connector.php line 55:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am very new to laravel and working through some of the laracasts (currently the [Fetching Data](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/7?autoplay=true) section).  While implementing the database stuff I am getting hung up.  I am not using Homebrew or Vagrant, I am using MAMP.  I was able to run `php artisan migrate` to create the tables from the tutorial just fine.  Now (following the tutorial) when I go to localhost:8000/cards I get the following error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

After tons of searching, I found that I needed to edit my .env file and config/database.php file which is what allowed me to run the `php artisan migrate` successfully.

**Here is my .env file:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=webapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

**Here is my database.php file:**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'webapp'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

So why am I not able to access the tutorial url localhost:8000/cards?  The error message references homebrew, but I don't use that I'm using MAMP.

[Using this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209536/laravel-5-database-issue), I already tried `php artisan config:clear` I also tried turning off and restarting MAMP but still receive the error.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the right way but removing the `env` variables from database.php seemed to fix the issue.  Not sure how to fix the above issue while still using `env`

Comment: Try logging into your mysql using the credentials specified on your .env file. If you are not able to login, then we have the issue.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be reading the .env file. Are you sure your .env file is there? not a .ent.txt file or anything like this? As you can see in the error page, it's trying to connect to homestead database instead of your webapp. Try to harcode your config values in database.php file to check it.

Answer (score 2):

With MAMP you need to use `unix_socket` to connect it to SQL. Modify `database.php` to add socket line as follow.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'unix_socket'=>'/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

And you will be good to go.